# Best way to make tabbaritem images smaller

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimage, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

What is the best way to make tabbaritem images smaller? Right now my images are 60x60 with @2x and they feel too larger. Id like to make them more like Facebook's tabbaritem size.. For some reason I feel like simply decreasing the image pixel size in PS is a bad idea..

Any ideas?

My tabbaritems:
[image: my tabbar]

Facebook tabbaritems:
[image: facebooks tabbar]

Comment: Not sure why the down votes.. Couldn't find a similar Q/A on SO....??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that I know of is to use PS to shrink the icon size but not shrink the canvas size.  This makes it so that iOS still displays it at 30x30pts, but they look smaller to the user because of the added padding.